# How to set the defaultSelectedItems value of Multi Person combo box in Powerapps?

Tags: powerapps-formula

I would like to set the **DefaultSelectedItems** value with multiple person selection from a previous Gallery.

Since I'm managing multiple people, I need to create a table with the selection but since I don't know the number of records selected by the user, I cannot create it.

For example, this is the code if the user selects 2 people:

*

```
Table(
    {
        '@odata.type': "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser",
        Claims: First(Gallery1.Selected.'Crew').Claims,
        Value: First(Gallery1.Selected.'Crew').DisplayName
    },
    {
        '@odata.type': "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser",
        Claims: Last(Gallery1.Selected.'Crew').Claims,
        Value: Last(Gallery1.Selected.'Crew').DisplayName
    }
)
```

*

How can I generalize it?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Kindly try the formula below

```
ForAll(Gallery1.AllItems, Crew)
```

Let me know if it works or not

Comment: Actually, I needed to add more code to reproduce the table. This is the code that it's working:

Set(varSharePoint, "'@odata.type': "&Char(34)&"#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser"&Char(34)   ) ;  ClearCollect(colCrewOnBoard, ForAll(Gallery1.AllItems, 'Crew'));ClearCollect(coldos, AddColumns(ShowColumns(Ungroup(colCrewOnBoard, "Value") ,"Claims","DisplayName") , "SharePoint" ,varSharePoint)  )

Comment: @Rodolfo Great, glad you got it sorted